# books on dual projective varieties and grassmannians

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, grassmannian

I'm currenty writing my bachelor degree thesis on the dual projective variety with focus on the biduality theorem. I'm looking for a book where to find this topics and a book that explains the grassmannians, possibly in an intelligible form. I've already been told to consult Harris' "Algebraic Geometry" and Shafarevich's "Basic Algebraic Geometry".

Comment: Israel M. Gelfand, Mikhail M. Kapranov, Andrei V. Zelevinsky: “Discriminants, Resultants, and Multidimensional Determinants” comes to mind.

Comment: "Projective Duality and Homogeneous Spaces" By Evgueni Tevelev.